# symfony2 assetic image not showing

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I am new to symfony2 using assetic.

```
{% set file %}{{ app.request.server.get('DOCUMENT_ROOT') ~ asset('bundles/robmhosearch/houses-thumbs/' ~ listing.code ~ '.jpg') }}{% endset %} {% if file_exists(file) %}
```

This is returning file doesn't exist for the images uploaded via ftp, while i have checked through ftp, file is present there.

Comment: where is the directory of uploaded images resides? i mean the path, is it in `/symfony_project/web/uploaded_imgs` ? for best symfony assets practices put the assets in `/web/` directory.

Comment: this is the location of the images in the root `/homes/bundles/robmhosearch/houses-thumbs`

Answer (score 0):

You should learn twig before try to coding http://twig.sensiolabs.org/.

Your code should be like this

```
{% set file = app.request.server.get('DOCUMENT_ROOT') ~ asset('bundles/robmhosearch/houses-thumbs/' ~ listing.code ~ '.jpg') %}
{% if file_exists(file) %}
```

And of course `file_exists` is not a builtin twig function so you have to code it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not written that code, i have changed that with yours but nothing seems to change. All other images are working fine except the images recently uploaded via ftp. i have cleared the twig cache as well.

Comment: Also lose the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, the `asset()` function should handle that.

Comment: Let me understand. Are you really uploading files inside of the bundle directory structure? You shouldn't but if the file exists and you are not viewing it means you have to do `php app/console assets:install --symlink`  or change your upload directory (this option is best)